# iOS subview best practice

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, subview

so here is what i've got; A `ViewController` with a root `UIView`(subclass) that has one subview that is a `UISegmentedControl`. The `UIView` draws concentric circles, and the `UISegmentedControl` changes the color of those circles. In order to do this I created my `UIView` in my `ViewControllers` loadView and added it to self.view, then I made the `UISegmentedControl` and added it as a subview of my `UIView`. Then I set the `UIView` as the target of the `UISegmentControl` and implemented a method in `UIView` to change the color and set that as the action. and this all works.

some code for reference

```
//setting up view hierarchy in viewcontroller.m

- (void)loadView{
    BNRHypnosisView *backgroundView = [[BNRHypnosisView alloc]init];
    self.view = backgroundView;
    UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc]initWithItems:@[@"Red",@"Green",@"Blue"]];
    [segmentedControl addTarget:backgroundView
                         action:@selector(changeColor:)
               forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [backgroundView addSubview:segmentedControl];
  }
```

```
//action
 - (void)changeColor:(UISegmentedControl *)sender{

      switch (sender.selectedSegmentIndex) {
        case 0:
          self.circleColor = [UIColor redColor];
          break;

        case 1:
          self.circleColor = [UIColor greenColor];
          break;

        case 2:
          self.circleColor = [UIColor blackColor];
          break;
      }
    }
```

So for my question...Here I am treating the super view as the controller of my subview, is this wrong? should leave everything to be handled by the view controller that owns my `UIView`. If so how could I do that in this situation?

-Thanks

and incase anyone picked up on it yes, this is one of the challenges from BNR iOS programming book :]

Comment: I don't see a problem with a view responding to the actions of another view. Is that what you're asking? I believe that if you can take code out of a view controller its probably a smart move. http://doing-it-wrong.mikeweller.com/2013/06/ios-app-architecture-and-tdd-1.html

Comment: I think it's not a very good design, the idea of the controller is to "control" and mediate data & views, your views should not handle logic.
Your view should probably have methods like `-changecolor:(UIColor*)color` but should not respond to events it does not generate, and even if it does, it should usually process these events, but when a logic question comes to mind, it should propagate the event to someone else to decide.

Comment: Yes, I just wasn't sure if I was defeating the purpose of having a view controller by having BNRHypnosisView be the target for segmentedControl. My biggest fear is that I'll pick up practices that won't work well when attempting larger projects so I want to make sure I have a solid grasp on how to structure everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MVC this is wrong. As you said you make a view to a controller and this never should be. Your aim should be to make most of your classes independent of other classes (loose coupling).

In your case you should move all code and especially the target action code to the view controller.
Change the action to target the viewController in viewDidLoad:

```
[segmentedControl addTarget:self
                     action:@selector(changeColor:)
           forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[backgroundView addSubview:segmentedControl];
```

and move the changeColor method to the view controller and cast the sender of the method to a UISegmented control:

```
- (void)changeColor:(id)sender{

     UISegmentedControl *segControl = (UISegmentedControl *) sender;

      switch (segControl.selectedSegmentIndex) {
        case 0:
          circleView.circleColor = [UIColor redColor];
          break;

        case 1:
          circleView.circleColor = [UIColor greenColor];
          break;

        case 2:
          circleView.circleColor = [UIColor blackColor];
          break;
      }
    }
```

for this to work you need to have a property to your circleView therefore make a property in the view controller and when creating the circleView assign it to the property.

```
@proprety (nonatomic, strong) BNRHypnosisView *circleView;
```

and in your loadView: method:

```
- (void)loadView{
    self.circleView = [[BNRHypnosisView alloc]init];
    self.view = self.circleView;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, taking this approach would this imply that any subview that will be modified while the app is running should be a property of the parent view, so that it can be accessed in the way above?

Comment: if you need to modify it later on you need to be able to address the view. so you need to have a property. In bigger programs one could make more view controllers and use the view controller containment to split a complex view with many subviews into more manageable views and view controllers.But since you are just learning this will come later :)